# Proving that the direct limit of a directed system is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations, limits-colimits

From Dummit & Foote, pg. 268:

> Let $I$ be an index set with a partial order.  Suppose for every pair of indices $i, j \in I$ with $i \leq j$ there is a map $\rho_{ij} : A_i \to A_j$ such that the following hold:
>
> **i.** $\rho_{jk} \circ \rho_{ij} = \rho_{ik}$
>
> **2.** $\rho_{ii} = 1$ for all $i \in I$.
>
> Let $B$ be the disjoint union of all the $A_i$.  Define a relation $\sim$ on $B$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if there exists $k$ with $i,j \leq k$ and $\rho_{ik}(a) = \rho_{jk}(b)$.

It's easy to show that the relation is reflexive and symmetric but I can't see how we can derive a relationship between $a \sim b $ and $b\sim c$ since the order on the index set $I$ is partial and not neccessarily total.  So how do I prove that this relation is indeed transitive as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is false as stated.

Let $I=\{2,3,5,6,15\}$, partially ordered by $i\preceq j$ iff $i\mid j$. For $i\in I$ let $A_i=\{i\}$. For $i,j\in I$ with $i\preceq j$ let $\rho_{ij}:A_i\to A_j$ be the only possible map: $\rho_{ij}(i)=j$.

Then $2\sim 3$, since $\rho_{2,6}(2)=\rho_{3,6}(3)=6$, and $3\sim 5$, since $\rho_{3,15}(3)=\rho_{5,15}(5)=15$, but $2\not\sim 5$.

It’s not sufficient that $I$ be partially ordered: $I$ must be *directed* by $\le$, so that for any $i,j\in I$ there is a $k\in I$ such that $i,j\le k$. Once you have that hypothesis, the result is pretty straightforward; leave a question if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: Ah, the book even states this.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: I’m relieved: I’d have been surprised to find such an error in Dummit and Foote!

Comment: I'm having trouble piecing it together.  I have $a \sim b \iff \exists i,j \leq k$ with $p_{ik}(a) = p_{jk}(b)$, $b \sim c \iff \exists i',j'\leq k'$ with $p_{i'k'}(b) = p_{j'k'}(c)$ and $\forall i,j \in I \exists k$ with $i,j \leq k$, and $p_{jk} \circ p_{ij} = p_{ik}$ whenever $i \leq j \leq k$.  Still thinking on it though.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: What you’re missing is that if $\rho_{ik}(a)=\rho_{jk}(b)$, then $a\in A_i$ and $b\in B_j$. Thus, the fact that $b\sim c$ means that there are $\ell,m\in I$ such that $c\in A_\ell$, $j,\ell\le m$, and $\rho_{jm}(b)=\rho_{\ell m}(c)$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I have to ruminate for a second on this at my dry-erase board.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: Let me stick with the notation from my previous comment. By directedness we have some $n\in I$ with $k,m\le n$. Now consider $\rho_{in}(a)$, $\rho_{jn}(b)$, and $\rho_{\ell n}(c)$.

Comment: In your first statement you made a mistake of re-using the variable $j$, we know that some $j'$ exists but not that it equals $j$

Comment: @EnjoysMath: No, the whole point is that it is *not* a mistake: from the fact that $\rho_{jk}(b)$ is defined, we know that $b\in A_j$. (When I wrote $b\in B_j$, I made a typo: it should have read $b\in A_j$.) The only functions $\rho$ having $b$ in their domain are the functions $\rho_{jn}$ for $n\in I$ with $j\le n$.

Comment: I've got it now.  Using the composition condition you can show that $\exists, i,j, \ell \leq k$ (by directedness, you can show both statements under one $k$.) such that $p_{ik}(a) = p_{jk}(b) = p_{\ell k}(c)$ done.  Thanks for teaching!

Comment: @EnjoysMath: You’re welcome!